# Parse Javascript SDK | Set array to undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, undefined

I have this array which when there is only one item left in the array, causes the array to be set to undefined.

Basically, this:

```
var array = {"example"}
```

To do this I say this:

```
if (array[1] == NULL){
    compiled = undefined;
}
info.add('assignment', compiled);
info.save(null, {
success:function(){//Whatever};
```

The problem is that parse does not update the object with the value undefined.

Any help?

Comment: What does this have to do with parsing? Did you mean parse.com? If so, how is that involved?

Comment: This is parse.com, sorry for not being clear enough, I thought parse idk was enough. Parse.com is used as my back end server to handle all user information, such as login, and other stuff. Parse holds the array that I am using.

Comment: your var array isn't an array, by the way

Comment: I fixed your tag. Next time, please use the [tag:parse.com] tag; [tag:parsing] has a different purpose. I know little about parse.com, but I don't see how a back-end service can "hold" a javascript array; the array is in the javascript engine. The original data may well be on the back-end server, but the issue you have seems to be entirely local. Of course, it is 100% possible that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the problem and made the research, here to share.

> The problem is that parse does not update the object with the value undefined.

Using `unset()` can clear the property of parse object, and then use `save()` to update property.
Here is the document : [Parse Object](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/1.10.2/Parse.Object.html)

In your use case, would be like ...

```
let array = ["example"]

if (array[1] == NULL) {
  info.unset('assignment'); //set assignment to undefined
}
else {
  //Other way to set assignment property
}
info.save(null, { success: function() { //Whatever };
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change this if statement:

```
if (array[1] == NULL){
  compiled = undefined;
}
```

TO this:

```
if(array.length > 1){
  compiled = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to my own question.

Basically, Parse has a function to unset an array to undefined.

I unset the parse array, then save it,

If my local array is not null, then I update the local array to the parse array.

I will provide code if anyone needs help!